# Index Match summation over multiple criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, sum, match, vlookup

I am trying to do an index match summation over multiple criteria. I have figured out the index match, but cannot sum multiple things that have been found. An example table is linked below:

[image: Example Table]

I am trying to dynamically sum by Country across multiple time frames - e.g. For Argentina what is the sum of A between dates 2/1/2019 and 5/1/2019? I can do an index match to extract a specific number, but cannot sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH to return the correct row to a SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(1:1000,MATCH("Argentina",A:A,0),0),1:1,">=" & Date(2019,1,2),1:1,"<=" & date(2019,1,5),2:2,"A")
```

Comment: Says "You've entered too many arguments for this function", highlighting `2:2` in `date(2019,1,50,2:2,"A")`

Comment: @dwirony yup missed a `)`.  That's what I get by typing directly in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SUMIFS`:

`=SUMIFS(B3:G3,B2:G2,"A",B1:G1,">=2/1/2019",B1:G1,"<=5/1/2019")`

[image: img1]

Comment: But can a SUMIFS be used dynamically for a country? E.g. if I wanted to reference another cell where the user changes from Argentina to Australia to Austria.